# Is there an algorithm of identifying different forms of "You" in a sentence AKA How to parse an English sentence

Tags: nlp, linguistics

How do I tell if "You" is used as a subject or an object in a sentence?

Comment: Are you asking how to parse English?

Comment: Yes, I think I'd better revise my title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a Natural Language Processing tool or library. There are a wide range mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_toolkits and you can use the one most suitable to your problem or language.

Most of these will carry out Part-of-Speech tagging (POSTagging) which identifies nouns, prepostions, etc. Then they will group the POS into NounPhrase, verbPhrase, etc. In simple terms:

> You see the cat

is parsed as

```
NP (PP you) VP (VB see DT the NN cat)
```

while

```
the cat sees you
```

is parsed as

```
NP (DT the NN cat) VP (VB sees PP you)
```

(schemes of POS vary)

The "you" is a personal pronoun (PP)  and if it occurs in the VP it's an object.

It gets more complicated than this, but this is a start

Answer (score 1):

NLP.  See http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/

Answer (score 0):

An engine you might want to try (I don't have the rep to comment being new to SE), the Attribute Logic Engine (ALE). Came across it in a grammar class in college. It's written in Prolog, which is a good language to understand if you're into Natural Language Processing, albeit a bit (read VERY) confusing.

ALE: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~gpenn/ale.html